# Web Scraping and Writing Data to JSON File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on some web scraping and want to write the results to a JSON file that I can use later instead of writing them to the console but I am not sure how to do that.  I want to store the data in a JSON file and use it to build a live search.  Below is the code.  I am still relatively new to this. Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ygrab.js"></script>
<script>        
$(function() {

var data = [
{
    //Lumen Learning SUNY Course Catalog
    url: 'https://courses.lumenlearning.com/catalog/suny', // url string rquired
    selector: 'div.book-data', // selector string rquired
    loop: true, // each boolean rquired
    result: [
        {
            name: 'Title', // key string rquired
            find: 'div.book-info h2', // selector child string rquired
            grab: {
                by: 'text', // attribut string rquired
                value: '' // attribut value string optional
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Author',
            find: 'div.book-info p a',
            grab: {
                by: 'text',
                value: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Link',
            find: 'div.book-info p a',
            grab: {
                by: 'attr',
                value: 'href'
            }
        }
    ]
},

//Open Textbook Library
{
    url: 'https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/SearchResults.aspx?subjectAreaId=99', // url string rquired
    selector: 'div.twothird', // selector string rquired
    loop: true, // each boolean rquired
    result: [
        {
            name: 'Title', // key string rquired
            find: 'h2', // selector child string rquired
            grab: {
                by: 'text', // attribut string rquired
                value: '' // attribut value string optional
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Author(s)',
            find: 'p',
            grab: {
                by: 'text',
                value: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Link',
            find: 'div.button-readmore a',
            grab: {
                by: 'attr',
                value: 'href'
            }
        }
    ]
}
];

ygrab(data, function(result) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save that file to disk. The browser does not allow it.
You can instead save it into your localstorage or pass it on your webserver to load it later.